# Return CookiesContainer object from WCF service to client

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7.1

I want to return CookiesContainer object from WCF service but I cann't return. I can return string from service.

Here is my **Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows">
        <forms cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" />
    </authentication>
 </system.web>

<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
     <!--behavior>-->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="true" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Here is my
**IService1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace WcfService1
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    CookieCollection GetCookies();

    [OperationContract]
    CookieContainer GetConnect(string uname, string password);
    //string GetConnect(string uname, string password);
}
}
```

Here is my **Service1.svc.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace WcfService1
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public CookieCollection GetCookies()
    {
        HttpWebRequest req;
        CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection();
        req = null;

        req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://site5.way2sms.com/");
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        // req.CookieContainer.Add(cc);

        req.CookieContainer.Add(cc);
        req.KeepAlive = true;

        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

        req.Referer = "http://site5.way2sms.com/content/index.html";

        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;

        return ((HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()).Cookies;
    }

    public CookieContainer GetConnect(string uid, string password)
    //public string GetConnect(string uid, string password)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req;
        HttpWebResponse res;
        Stream str;


        //try
        //{
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://site5.way2sms.com/Login1.action");
            req.Method = "POST";
            CookieContainer con = new CookieContainer();
            req.CookieContainer = con;
            req.CookieContainer.Add(GetCookies());
            req.KeepAlive = true;

            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

            req.Referer = "http://site5.way2sms.com/content/index.html";

            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username=" + uid + "&password=" + password);
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uid, password);
            req.ContentLength = data.Length;
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;

            str = req.GetRequestStream();
            str.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            str.Close();


            res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            string iduri = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(res.ResponseUri.Query).Get("id");

            if (iduri != "")
            {
                return con;
                //return "Success";
            }
            else
            {
                res.Close();
                str.Close();

                return null;
                //return "Fail";
            }
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{

        //}
    }
  }
 }
```

Here is my **Login.xaml.cs**

```
    private void btnSignin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uid = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
        string password = txtPassword.Password.Trim();

        networkIsAvailable = Checknetwork();
        if (networkIsAvailable)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Network Avaliable", "Avaliable", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            //svc.GetcookiesCompleted += new EventHandler<GetcookiesCompletedEventArgs>(svc_Get_Cookies);
            //svc.GetcookiesAsync(); 

            txtblockcheck.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            svc.GetConnectCompleted += new EventHandler<GetConnectCompletedEventArgs>(svc_Get_Connected);
            svc.GetConnectAsync(uid, password);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your network", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }


    void svc_Get_Connected(object send, GetConnectCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        CookieContainer con = e.Result;
    }
```

When I return CookiesContainer from service I get this following error

There was no endpoint listening at **http://localhost:3922/Service1.svc** that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I doesn't understand how can I return CookiesContainer Object from service to client 
can anybuddy tell me ?

Comment: The error message seems unrelated to the problem you suggest.

Comment: when I return CookieContainer object it gives an error that I have mentioned above

Comment: I can return string from service easily. but I am not able to return cookiescontainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, to help debug it, I would run the serialization manually.  CookieContainer is not XmlSerializable (but is Soap Serializable so that shouldn't be the problem really)  but I never like sending anything other than POCO objects that I write over webservices.

Here is my generic serialization methods, maybe just feed it the byte array, or `Convert.ToBase64String()` and return that.  If nothing else this will absolutely confirm that your webservice is working as expected.

Using the methods i have below:

```
public byte[] GetConnect(string uid, string password)
{
    ...

    if (iduri != "")
    {
        return SerializeObject(con);
    }
}
```

-

```
void svc_Get_Connected(object send, GetConnectCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    CookieContainer con = DeserializeObject<CookieContainer >(e.Result);
}
```

-

```
public static byte[] SerializeObject<T>(T obj)
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter xs = new BinaryFormatter();
            xs.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] xml)
{
    BinaryFormatter xs = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xml);
    return (T)xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how do I use this?

Comment: How do I use BinaryFormatter in .xaml.cs file? I gives error i.e. missing assembly

Comment: My service successfully return SerializeObject(con). Now I didn't understand how to call DeserializeObject funcation from svc_Get_Connected funcation

Comment: I can't use BinaryFormatter in Windows phone so is there any way to write DeserializaObject method?

Answer (score 0):

Well try this:

1. In your client project, go to your **Service Reference**, right click, and then hit *Update Service Reference*. Every time you make a change on your service sign (any method or param), you have to update this reference. Maybe you did some changes and forget to do this step.
2. Just in case, set params names equals in your Interface and Service definition. Notice `CookieContainer GetConnect(string uname, string password);` defined in you *interface* specifies `string uname`, but *Service1* implementation declares `CookieContainer GetConnect(string uid, string password);`, using `string uid`. Shouldn't be a problem, but just for the sake of tidyness.

Comment: I get same error. the service could not return cookiecontainer object.

Comment: Isolate it, I've just tried setting up a brand new solution includind two projects, WCF and a Console client, used the same code as you and it's working. So there's **nothing wrong with your code using default configurations**.

Comment: How do i isolate it? can you please post your code? your web.config,service1.svc,Iservice1.cs

Comment: In my first comment I told you that I used the same code, so it's not necessary that I post it. I also say that I created the solution with this code and default configurations to both client and service and it worked, then you should try to do the same, that way you'll find what's wrong.

Comment: I have tried this all thing in new solution with same settings but problem was not solved Again it gives same error in new solution.
It gives same error i.eThere was no endpoint listening

Comment: Ok see [**this**](http://www.sendspace.com/file/b48cb8) is the VS Solution. You have to run into other problem than *"There was no endpoint listening"*, because in fact the problem is the serialization of CoockieContainer object (see, if you return only `new CookieContainer();` you won't get any error). Use [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to debug, it will show you the error itself (which might be with *System.Net.PathList*).